# Git File Restore After Committing Twice

Tags: git, github, restore, git-commit

Suppose I have a file called header.php, and I delete it by accident. I continue working, make several commits and then notice the absence. Then, due to my lack of knowledge on how to do this, I copy a version of this file manually from the master branch and re-create it. I then commit this change and some others later.

My question is how do I restore it properly from the first deleted version? I found an answer here that talks about the case of no commit and the last commit related to this file. However, for me, it is the second before last commit related to this file.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-recover-a-file-I-deleted-in-my-local-repo-from-the-remote-repo-in-Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the commit which deleted the file, run:

```
git log -1 -- header.php
```

The `-1` option tells `git log` to stop after showing one commit, and since you limit the history to commits touching `header.php`, it has to be the commit where it was removed.

Then, to restore it:

```
git checkout <commit-id>^ -- header.php
```

Where `<commit-id>` is the identifier of the commit you found with the first command. Note the `^` after it, meaning "the parent of".

Comment: I think it did it. I had to use -2 to get to the proper commit. Thanks! What does the carrot-top mean?